# Cyclic Decompositions and the Rational form

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $T$ be a linear operator on the the finite dimensional space $V$, let $R$ be the range of $T$. Then, I have to show that

(a) $R$ has a complementary $T$-invariant subspace if and only if $R$ is independent of the null space $N$ of $T$.

(b) If $R$ and $N$ are independent, I need to prove that $N$ is the unique $T$-invariant subspace complementary to $R$.

Please suggest how to proceed.

I supposed $R$ has a complementary $T$-invariant subspace, say, $W$. Then $R$ should be $T$-admissible. I assumed to the contrary, that $R$ intersection $T$ is not equal to $\{\mathbf{0}\}$. I took a point in the intersection but could not proceed further. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: I supposed R has a complementary T - invariant subspace, say, W. Then , R should be T- admissible. I assumed to the contrary, that R intersection T is not equal to {0}. I took a point in the intersection but could not proceed further. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) If $R\cap N =\{\mathbf{0}\}$, then you should be able to use the Rank-Nullity Theorem to show that $R+N=V$, and you are done.

Conversely, if there exists $W$ such that $R\cap W=\{\mathbf{0}\}$, $R+W=V$, and $W$ is $T$-invariant, what can you say about $T(\mathbf{w})$ for any $\mathbf{w}\in W$? It is certainly in $W$... is it in $R$ as well?

(b) As above, suppose that $R+W=V$, with $R\cap W=\{\mathbf{0}\}$ and $T(W)\subseteq W$. Show that $W\subseteq N$ and conclude, for example, using dimension, that $W=N$.

P.S. This has *nothing* to do with the rational canonical form, nor with cyclic decompositions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind and informative reply.

Comment: Ummm, I was studying Hoffman & Kunze too guys (chapter 7, the rational and Jordan canonical forms) and stumble across this question. I consider this transformation on a 3-dimensional space:
$$T(\alpha_1)=\alpha_1 , T(\alpha_2)=\alpha_1 ,T(\alpha_3)=0 $$
clearly $N = \{ \alpha_3 \}$ and $R = \{ \alpha_1 \} $ and $R,N$ are independent. The complement of $R$ is $R'=\{\alpha_2,\alpha_3\}$ which is not invariant under $T$. I can't resolve this paradox. Please help guys :-(

Comment: @K.K.McDonald. First, the range is the span of $\alpha_1$, not just $\alpha_1$. Second, the Nullspace is not just (the span of) $\alpha_3$: for example, $\alpha_1-\alpha_2$ is also in the nullspace. Finally, there is no such thing as "the complement of $R$". *There are lots of complements to $R$*! For example, $\mathrm{span}(\alpha_1+\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ is *also* a complement to $R$ (check it!).

Comment: @K.K.McDonald: Note that your calculations couldn't **possibly** be correct; the rank-nullity theorem tells you that the rank plus the nullity equals the dimension of the space, but here you give a linear transformation from 3-dimensional space, and claim that the rank and the nullity are both 1...

Comment: Jesus! xD xD, you're correct bro! I forgot linear transformation is indeed 1 to 1, so you couldn't map two vectors to one vector. Thank you, my mind is a whole again.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald: I'm sorry, but that's *nonsense*. Linear transformations don't need to be one to one! No, not only were you mistaken at first, now you are completely mistaken about what it was you were mistaken about!

Comment: it's not one to one, i accept, because the whole of nullspace gets mapped to zero. But other than nullspace, the linear transformation is one to one.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald: No, that's still nonsense. If $v$ is any vector, and $n$ is a nonzero vector in the nullspace, then $v$ and $v+n$ both get mapped to the same thing, even though $v\neq v+n$. You're just utterly confused and mistaken.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald Your example is the **linear** function $f(a,b,c) = (a+b,0,0)$. This is linear. The nullspace is the span of $(1,-1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. The range is the span of $(1,0,0)$. In this **linear** function, $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ and $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,1)$ all get mapped to the same thing. But you are (i) just not calculating the nullspace correctly; and (ii) thinking that there is a single "complement" to subspace (there's infinitely many complements to every proper nonzero subspace). And now you are saying things that just patently wrong about linear transformations.

Comment: Wow! you're right man, I should think it thoroughly again  (-__- ').